# query function not work in php7

Tags: php

first of all, I want to thank you to everyone who gives this post attention. I got a problem when migrating code from php5 to php7. I actually don't know what is going wrong in my code

```
class database {
    public function __construct () {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysqli_select_db($conn, 'crm');
    }

    public function view_chart(){
        $data = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from t_chart");
        while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
            $hasil[] = $d;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }

    foreach($db->view_chart() as $x){

        echo "<option value='$x[id_chart_cat]'>$x[chart_name]</option>";

    }
```

the `view_chart()` not work but it's work in php4 as well. anyone here can tell me what is going wrong with this code? I really appreciate any answer which is related to this question. Thank you.

Comment: 1. foreach cant be in the body of the class, has to be in a method. 2. `$conn` is a local variable and cannot be used in other methods, this should be a class property.  Honestly this would not work in PHP5 not by a long shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `$conn` as class member variable so it's accessible from other class functions.

**Do:**

```
class database {
    public $conn; // added
    public function __construct () {
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // modified
        mysqli_select_db($this->conn, 'crm'); // modified
    }

    public function view_chart(){
        $data = mysqli_query($this->conn, "select * from t_chart"); // modified
        while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
            $hasil[] = $d;
        }
        return $hasil;
    }

    foreach($db->view_chart() as $x){

        echo "<option value='$x[id_chart_cat]'>$x[chart_name]</option>";

    }
```

Comment: Not as simple as that, you have the right idea in that it is a scope issue. BUT `function __construct(){ $conn =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");}` is not `$this->conn`  ergo just adding a property does not quite do it.

Comment: Cool, now fix one other issue, for them.  It's a syntax error as you cant use foreach outside of the class methods.  :)  sorry.  I believe that should be outside of the class entirely, and the class is assigned to $db, so you need a closing `}`

Comment: It's what the OP posted. I just copied, modified and pasted as is.

Comment: It's still wrong.  I would close the class and leave the foreach out.  Then your code is syntactically fine...  It looks like `$db` is an instance of `database`,  Then I will give you an upvote.  Good work on the scope issues.

Comment: It's your choice, let me know if you fix it as I suggested and I will give you a +1.  Good Luck!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the OP accepted it anyways. Thanks for the comments tho.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to help improve your answer, which was correct in idea.  So no offense intended.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

when I updated my PHP-scripts to PHP7 I had issues with

```
mysqli_fetch_array()
```

you should replace it with a function like

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc()
```

Comment: When I updated my code from php4 I had some issues where the class constructor was the same name as the class so I had to replace all those with `__construct` that was back in 2007 though... lol.  And it wasn't my code it was a site written by someone else in 2001-2002  But it's probably just as relevant to this question, as I don't really think this code worked in PHP5x.  lol

Comment: True story, my first professional gig was updating that stuff, and i barely knew PHP at the time.

Comment: i feel the same with u @ArtisticPhoenix. lol. it was happen to me too.

Answer (score 0):

did you first check and make sure your connection was being made? and how i always did it in 7 was like this

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "password";
        $dbName = "test";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbName);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    ?>
```

then you can do

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM whatever";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $hasil = [];
?>
```

then you should be able to just do

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $hasil[] = $row;
    }
    return $hasil;
```

then go into your foreach...not sure if that's what your looking for but hope it helps